# Haversine formula in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, computational-geometry, geospatial

This is an implementation of the [Haversine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) formula in Microsoft Transact SQL.

How can I simplify the function?

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Haversine(@point_a geography, @point_b geography)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @result FLOAT
    DECLARE @lat1 FLOAT = @point_a.Lat
    DECLARE @lon1 FLOAT = @point_a.Long
    DECLARE @lat2 FLOAT = @point_b.Lat
    DECLARE @lon2 FLOAT = @POINT_b.Long

    DECLARE @earth_radius FLOAT =  6371
    DECLARE @dLat FLOAT = RADIANS(@lat2 - @lat1)
    DECLARE @dLon FLOAT = RADIANS(@lon2 - @lon1) 
    SET @lat1 = RADIANS(@lat1)
    SET @lat2 = RADIANS(@lat2)

    DECLARE @a FLOAT
    SET @a = POWER(SIN(@dLat/2),2) + COS(@lat1)*COS(@lat2)*POWER(SIN(@dLon/2),2)
    DECLARE @c FLOAT = 2*ASIN(SQRT(@a))
    SET @result = @earth_radius * @c;
    RETURN @result
END
```

Here is a test of the function:

```
DECLARE @target_point geography = (SELECT GeoLocation FROM WA_Features WHERE FEATURE_NAME = 'Seattle' AND FEATURE_CLASS='Populated Place');

SELECT FEATURE_NAME, dbo.Haversine(@target_point, GeoLocation)*0.62137 FROM WA_Features WHERE FEATURE_CLASS='Lake' ORDER BY dbo.Haversine(@target_point, GeoLocation);
```

Am I calling the function properly? And is there a way to call it only once per row?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need the function? To measure the distance (in miles) between two points? Then you want to select all points of a certain type and order them by distance from a given origin.

With [a CTE (common table expression)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)  you can simplify things a lot too.

But, the real issue, is that you should use the functions already available in the geography datatype: [STDistance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933808.aspx). This STDistance function returns the 'LineString' distance, which is 0.25% accurate to the geodesic distance. Additionally, this is better than the 0.5% accuracy of the Haversine distance.

So, by the sounds of it, you have horribly overcomplicated this process. Consider [this (SQLFiddle example here too)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88019/5/0):

```
Select s.FEATURE_NAME as SName,
       s.GeoLocation.Lat as SLat,
       s.GeoLocation.Long as SLong,
       t.FEATURE_NAME as TName,
       t.GeoLocation.Lat as TLat,
       t.GeoLocation.Long as TLong,
       s.GeoLocation.STDistance(t.GeoLocation) * 0.00062137 as Distance
from Features s,
     Features t
where s.FEATURE_NAME = 'Seattle'
  and s.FEATURE_CLASS = 'Populated Place'
  and t.FEATURE_CLASS = 'Lake'
order by Distance desc
```

Answer (score 2):

For a function that calculates the great circle distance on Earth between two points, `Haversine` is an odd name.  It's analogous to calling the function for finding the distance between two Cartesian coordinates `Pythagorean` instead of `Distance`.

Take care to use consistent capitalization (you slipped up in `@POINT_b`).

The implementation looks fine.  Personally, I would eliminate the `@c` and `@result` variables, as they just increase mental baggage.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GreatCircleDist(@point_a geography, @point_b geography)
RETURNS FLOAT
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @lat1 FLOAT = @point_a.Lat
    DECLARE @lon1 FLOAT = @point_a.Long
    DECLARE @lat2 FLOAT = @point_b.Lat
    DECLARE @lon2 FLOAT = @point_b.Long

    DECLARE @earth_radius FLOAT =  6371
    DECLARE @dLat FLOAT = RADIANS(@lat2 - @lat1)
    DECLARE @dLon FLOAT = RADIANS(@lon2 - @lon1) 
    SET @lat1 = RADIANS(@lat1)
    SET @lat2 = RADIANS(@lat2)

    DECLARE @a FLOAT
    SET @a = POWER(SIN(@dLat/2),2) + COS(@lat1)*COS(@lat2)*POWER(SIN(@dLon/2),2)
    RETURN 2 * ASIN(SQRT(@a)) * @earth_radius
END
```